# Performance of update existing contact in Android so slow

Tags: android, contacts

i have a problem in update existing contact in Android. My code execute about 400 contact but it take me about 20s to update it. Here is my code.

```
public class Contact {
    private long contactId;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private int phoneType;
}
```

Then i try to update each contact filter by ID and Type:

ArrayList list = arrayLists[0];

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
     Contact contact = list.get(i);
     long contactID = contact.getContactId();
     String newPhoneNumber = contact.getPhoneNumber();
     int phoneType = contact.getPhoneType();
     updateContact(contactID, newPhoneNumber, phoneType);           
}
```

Here is my updateContact funtion:

```
private void updateContact(long contactID, String newPhoneNumber, int phoneType) {
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        String where = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE + " = ?";
        String[] whereParams = new String[]{contactID + "", phoneType + ""};
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, newPhoneNumber);
        Uri dataUri = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;
        cr.update(dataUri, contentValues, where, whereParams);
    }
```

I tried other method to update contact but it also take same time ( about 20s for 400 contact)

```
 private void updateContact(long contactID, String newPhoneNumber, int phoneType) {
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        String where = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " +
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE + " = ?";
        String[] params = new String[]{contactID + "", phoneType + ""};
        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withSelection(where, params)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, newPhoneNumber)
                .build());

        try {
            cr.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

What should i do, how can i improve the performance of update job. I expert it can update 400 contact in 3-5s

Comment: You are updating all the contact in loop that's why its taking too much time. if you want to update one existing contact information then you do not to write that in loop.

Comment: I want to update the list of contacts, so i have to put it in loop

Comment: You are call a `applyBatch` operation, however you are calling it contact by contact. Thus, you lose all benefit of it. You should try to create as many ContentProviderOperation as possible and, then, apply it all at once.